# Can visual studio be installed in linux?

Tags: linux

Can visual studio IDE be installed in linux ? Visual studio includes many programming languages like c # , F# etc. so for web development .net platform with c # programming is used. For back end development sql queries are used . In linux platform, What can be an alternative to .net.  I have researched that there are many options like java, PHP etc.

My question is whether the visual studio can be installed in linux or there are alternative languages or platforms for it.

Comment: If you are using linux, why not choose a language that linux is more suited to develop in?  You have C++, PHP, Python and the list goes on.

Answer (score 0):

Can visual studio IDE be installed in linux? Probably not. But there is free .NET implementation on linux [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/). And the .NET cross-platform IDE [MonoDevelop](http://www.monodevelop.com/).

Comment: but will mono will support all he features which a  microsoft .net supports.

Comment: Thanks but are there any other alternative other than .net based visual studio which is specifically for linux users for web server based applications

Comment: @Thaiyal Nayaki: Only .NET is suitable for cross platform executuion (thanks to MSIL for providing suitable abstraction (.NET is like JVM)). So read carefuly Mono documentation for full understanding about  visual studio assembly support.

Comment: I am not asking for cross platform execution.. Am I asking what does the linux users generally prefer for designing web server based applications . Which language they would prefer just as for windows people use .net, Java etc

Comment: @Thaiyal Nayaki: JAVA, PHP, Ruby on Rails, Python, and many more.

Comment: @Thaiyal Nayaki: Choose what you like, but they all without MSVS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can install [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/VirtualBox) and use it to spin up a virtual-windows-machine. On that VM you can install VS or any other Windows application.

Comment: Thanks but are there any other alternative other than .net based visual studio which is specifically for linux users for web server based applications

Comment: @ThaiyalNayaki I doubt it, but what's wrong with working on a VM ? I do it all the time and it works great!

Comment: Thanks It is for a small project for an organization so only asked... if it is for myself i will try with virtual box